# Extracting data from NSF database file - Domino

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have an nsf database file from a domino web application based on Lotus Domino version 6.5.

Any ideas on how I can extract the data? The data contains word,pdf and html documents.

Comment: Do you have Notes client? Is the only data you want in the attachments? Most data in Notes databases tends to be in fields on the forms, not in attachments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Notes designer client [from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/?S_CMP=LSDL) with no restrictions as well as the [Notes and administrator clients](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsndad/index.html) with a 90-day evaluation period. Then you should be able to access the data natively.

Answer (score 4):

The word and pdf documents can be detached:

```
For a=1 To coll.count
     Set doc=coll.GetNthDocument(a)
     Set rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("Body")
     Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
        oname="c:\" + o.name
        Call o.ExtractFile( oname )
        Call o.Remove
     End Forall
     Call doc.Save(True, False)
  Next
```

The code above is just an example, the point is to find the embedded object and use `o.ExtractFile( oname )`

If the html documents are also attached files, you can do the same for those. If not, it is a different story.

Comment: Thanks, what programming language is that? I have no experience using Domino, I've just got the file and I'm trying to figure out how to get the data out.

Comment: It is lotusscript. You will need the designer client and definitely the help file.

Comment: It is important to get the HTML question right, do you need the html, is it formatted in the notes form, or is it an attachment. If it is formatted in the form, it might be easier (in your case) to bring the site online and use a web crawler to fetch the data.

Comment: I've managed to do exactly what you suggested (using a web crawler), however there is also a Java applet that contains documents I need that the web crawler can't get to.